# SecurityException even though permission is set

Tags: android, securityexception, powermanager

I´m trying to keep the screen on of the device with my app.

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "bbbb");
```

It throws a SecurityExeption. I have declared the permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK "></uses-permission>
```

in my Manifest.

Is there any other permission required?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us a logcat dump of the security exception?

There are other methods of keeping a screen alive.

For instance you can add this to the layout view.

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Other ways is to call this method right after setContentView (onCreate)
has been called.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: hard, because my app reacts on usb plug in :D but I´ll try it. okay, but I don´t want to keep the screen alive in my app. it´s just a broadcastreceiver which should trigger a global "no-standby"